# express-mysql-session "expires" value of session is messed up

Tags: mysql, express, session

I'm using express-mysql-session as a session store for my server and every time I check my db, I see that all sessions have an "expires" value that goes back to the 70s (in milliseconds).

And even though I set `checkExpirationInterval` to 300000, no session ever gets cleared.

```
var sessionStore = new MySQLStore({
host: process.env.DB_HOST,
port: 3306,
user: process.env.DB_USER,
password: process.env.DB_PASS,
database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
clearExpired: true,
checkExpirationInterval: 300000,
expiration: 1000 })
```

Is there something I can do about it?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to re-create your exact issue:

**A. Here are my, my-sql-store options:**

```
var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'myDB',
    clearExpired: true,
    checkExpirationInterval: 30000, //30 seconds
    expiration: 1000
}
var sessionStore = new MySqlStore(options);
```

**B. Here is where I mount the session in my app:**

```
app.use(session({
    key: 'this_is_my_key',
    secret: 'it_is_a_secret',
    store: sessionStore,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))
```

**Conclusion**
With the above information, my session does **remove** expired session from my sql database in 30000 ms or 30 seconds.